# Internet Explorer Nightly Build

Tags: asp.net, internet-explorer, browser

Where i can download nightly build for IE?

I searched google and found nothing.

Its really good if Microsoft offer nightly/standalone build.

Majority of good browsers like Firefox, Chrome, Safari offer nightly builds.

IE got a development build?

Answer (score 5):

You are mistaken.

Chrome does not offer nightly builds, although they do have an open source project called Chromium that does offer nightly builds (Chrome is based on Chromium, but they are not identical).

Similarly, Safari does not offer nightly builds either, though again they have an open source project based on WebKit.

In fact, the only major browser that offers nightly builds is Firefox.  A number of minor browsers (usually based on gecko or webkit) also offer nightly builds, but aren't particularly important.

IE, Opera, Chrome, Safari, etc only offer developer snapshots at various stages of the development cycle.

So your assertion that because IE doesn't offer nightly builds it must be a bad browser is not a valid argument.

EDIT:

There is not yet any development build for IE11, nor would I expect one for at least a year.  Microsoft just released IE10 officially for Windows 7, and it's been out for Windows 8 since November.

Answer (score 0):

There is no general availability of development builds of IE. Microsoft simply does not do that.

They do provide beta releases of IE prior to releasing a new version -- for both IE9 and IE10, there were a series of pre-releases prior to general release, but this process was carefully controlled by Microsoft -- there were only a handful of pre-releases; certainly not a nightly build.

The main reason for this is that IE is not open source. The developers of the open source browsers have a culture and an incentive to release more often, and nightly builds are a result of that. Microsoft's culture and release strategy is completely different.

Answer (score 0):

There is Internet Explorer 11 (not officialy released, you can take it as nightly build) but right now it's only on Windows 8.1 Preview.